# Force encoding method in expo camera

Tags: react-native, encoding, expo, react-native-ios, react-native-camera

I am using react native and expo camera to build an app that can upload videos to my website. Everything works fine on Android but on newer iPhones it uploads a blank video that still has audio. I think this is because of the new iOS encoding method HEVC rather than the typical H264. Is there any way to force expo camera to encode in H264?

Comment: anyone knows how to do it?